# What's a screenshot application which will auto-upload to imgur?

Tags: screenshot

Is there an equivalent to Imgur on Ubuntu?

I am looking for an application that has the simple workflow of:

- Taking a screenshot.
- Having it auto-upload in the click of a button.

Comment: Imgur is a website, which means it'll also work on Ubuntu. Are you thinking of a desktop application that uploads its images to Imgur? Also, have you looked at http://imgur.com/apps?

Answer (score 24):

You can do this with `shutter` as well, which is available in the repositories. Simply take a screenshot and then click *export* (see screenshots) and you are presented with a comprehensive number of alternatives, including the option of Ubuntu One.

You can upload to places like imgur, imageshack either as a guest or you can use your account if you have one. See the second screenshot for this, which details the uploading preferences settings of `shutter`, accessed via edit > preferences > upload tab.

For more details on the `shutter` project see the [official site](http://shutter-project.org/) of this very useful program.

[image]
[image]

Comment: And it supports Imgur!

Comment: This is not answering the question. Shutter is unable to upload automatically. This feature was asked for in 2010 and never implemented: https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/585197

Comment: @Fidelix Well nobody has answered the question properly then...You better put an answer yourself if you have any ideas

Comment: Unfortunately, I never found a good application for this on Linux. Windows has the edge with Sharex, which is an AMAZING piece of software.

Comment: Not included in Debian as the libraries are old.

Answer (score 14):

### [Nanoshot](http://nanoshot.sourceforge.net/)

Nanoshot - it's an easy to use program for Linux, which will help you take screenshots and upload them to a hosting site of your choice

**Features**

- Take full size screenshots
- Take screenshot of windows, including the active window
- Take desktop screenshots
- Take screenshots of web pages
- Capture frames from video using Gstreamer and Mplayer
- Upload screenshots to popular image hosting sites, such as imgur, flickr and imageshack.

**Installation:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nanoshot/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nanoshot
```

**Screenshots:**

*Nanoshot menu:*

[image: Application menu]

*Upload options:*

[image: Upload to]

*Website:*

http://nanoshot.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Excellent. You can select the area and you can move/resize the rectangle just like in Gimp.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work anymore. I'm getting this error `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nanoshot/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`.

Answer (score 5):

### This answer was posted in reply to the original question (which could have use an alternative to imgur).

MediaFire express (as mentioned by lkjoel) does exactly this.

Example:
[image: Taking A Screenshot]
Taking the screenshot.

[image: Editing and uploading]
Editing and uploading

[image: After screenshot]
After the screenshot has been taken, a link is available.

You need a MediaFire account, of course. That asside, the application is simple and easy to use, and you get loads of space to store your files online, with nice previews.

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 3):

Also there's a simple application for Ubuntu 12.04 and above, "fileshare", which was written in PyGTK by me:

http://aikikode.github.io/fileshare/

It's very much like Nanoshot but with only the core functionality for quick and easy grabbing the screenshot and upload to Imgur:

1. click 'Select screen area to grab...' menu item
2. select the screen area
3. view the preview and press 'Upload' button
4. the image URL will appear in upper right corner of the screen and this URL will also be automatically 'copied' - paste it anywhere you need to share the image

The application also have Imgur accounts support - click 'Log in' to connect the application to your Imgur account and all the screenshots will be uploaded to your Imgur web page.

It allows to share already saved images: click 'Show File Grabber' and a small Imgur icon will appear - just drag'n'drop image file there and it will be uploaded to Imgur the same way.

Answer (score 1):

All the [Imgur Uploading Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E7EQ.jpg) listed below are completely free to use. There are descriptions of each Imgur Uploading Tool and links to download them at the previously mentioned link.

• Firefox Extension
• Chrome Extension
• Hyperdesktop - Screenshot Uploader
• Right click -> Send To -> Imgur
• MyImgur
• OS X Dashboard Widget
• ImgurBar
• Cross-platform Desktop Uploader
• Linux Screenshot Uploader
• Wordpress Plugin
• OS X Command Line Uploader
• Bash Script Uploader

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small python script to do the same. It captures the screenshot of the screen , uploads in imgurl , copies the url into clipboard , deletes the created image file from your desktop in just one keyboard shortcut.

This script was written for OS X, for `Ubuntu` in line `20` of `screenshot.py` use `xfce4-screenshooter` instead.

[Script Link](http://iyask.me/AutoScreenshotUploader/)

[Video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSHaXGYkEOw)

Answer (score 0):

Flameshot!!! Love it. Does everything I can think of with screenshots.

## Screenshot upload to Imgur tool:

sudo apt install flameshot

Head to the system "Settings" and navigate your way to the "Keyboard" settings.

You will find all the keyboard shortcuts listed there, ignore them and scroll down to the bottom. 
Now, you will find a + button.

Click the “+” button to add a custom shortcut. 
You need to enter the following in the fields you get:

Name: Flameshot
Command: /usr/bin/flameshot gui

Finally, set the shortcut to F5 by just pressing the F5 key (I had this key available on Ubuntu 18.04)

When you hit F5 now you will be walked through with dialogs and icons.
The cloud Icon instantly puts it on Imgur with a tiny url to share in any web posts.

[IMgur Desktop Shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUyhN.jpg)