# App for taking a screenshot, editing and uploading it to a server

Tags: kde, screenshot

Do you know of any app that can take a screenshot using a keyboard shortcut, open a window for selecting a region of the screenshot and upload it to a hosting like imgur?

Preferably for KDE.

Comment: Install kipi-plugins, it contains a module to export images to imgur from any KDE application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[clip2net](http://clip2net.com/en/) image sharing site has a client for Linux, which i have just tried - works pretty well and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can view some options (none specifically KDE AFAICT) at this question: [What's a screenshot application which will auto-upload to imgur?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177921/whats-a-screenshot-application-which-will-auto-upload-to-imgur)

Answer (score 0):

your looking for this
does exactly what you want

http://sirupsen.com/a-simple-imgur-bash-screenshot-utility/

Comment: But i cannot interactively crop a region from the screenshot... That is in the question

Comment: But today i accidentally found a command in ubuntu called `import`. If you do `import screenshot.png` you will be able to select a region and it will be saved to the given file. You might want incorporate it into the script in the answer

Comment: Yes, this script will interactively let you select a region of the screen.